# Verificando tempo da execução de uma chamada em ADVPL

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, advpl

Minha `VerifyOnServ(nTimeOut)`, nem sempre está obedecendo ao `nTimeOut` passado, seja por causa dela ou do servidor com o qual ela se comunica.

Então precisei de uma insistência em sua execução obedecendo ao `nTimeOut`

Segue o código:

```
cTic := Time()
While .Not. lExpired

    cResponse := VerifyOnServ(nTimeOut)
    cTac := Time()

    If cResponse != nil
       exit
    EndIf

    cElapsed := ElapTime(cTic, cTac)
    nElapsed := VAL(SUBSTR(cElapsed, 1, 2))*(3600) + VAL(SUBSTR(cElapsed, 4, 2))*(60) + VAL(SUBSTR(cElapsed, 7, 2))

    lExpired := nElapsed > nTimeOut
EndDo
```

O código acima supriu minhas necessidades e garante as tentativas de execução respeitando o `nTimeOut` passado. OK.

Gostaria de saber se existe um modo mais *elegante* ou *otimizado* de reescrever a linha:

```
nElapsed := VAL(SUBSTR(cElapsed, 1, 2))*(3600) + VAL(SUBSTR(cElapsed, 4, 2))*(60) + VAL(SUBSTR(cElapsed, 7, 2))
```

Tendo em vista todo o custo de desmembrar o `cElapsed` em hora, minuto e segundos, transforma-los em segundos e somá-los para por fim comparar com o `nTimeOut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em essência não dá. Eu não gosto da solução como um todo, mas não posso afirmar que não seja a melhor opção neste caso por não conhecer o problema em si e as consequências de fazer o que está fazendo (só acho esquisito ter que fazer isto e parece gambiarra, mas só opinião sem base, não leva a sério). E tem variável desnecessária no código.

Quando a linha em questão dá só para manter uma padrão e eliminar o que é redundante, nada além disto:

```
nElapsed := Val(Substr(cElapsed, 1, 2)) * 3600 + Val(Substr(cElapsed, 4, 2)) * 60 + Val(Substr(cElapsed, 7, 2))
```

Fora isso poderia criar uma função que faça isso e possa chamar em vez de escrever tudo isto outras vezes, por ser um detalhes de implementação faz sentido, até mesmo se não for usar em outros locais (e eu acho que teria utilidade outras vezes), algo assim:

```
Function ElapTime2Sec(cElapsed)
Return Val(Substr(cElapsed, 1, 2)) * 3600 + Val(Substr(cElapsed, 4, 2)) * 60 + Val(Substr(cElapsed, 7, 2))
```

Aí poderia fazer:

```
cTic := Time()
While .T.
    If VerifyOnServ(nTimeOut) != nil .or. ElapTime2Sec(ElapTime(cTic, Time())) <= nTimeOut
       Exit
    EndIf
EndDo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ADVPLElapseTime.prg).

Answer (score 0):

A alternativa mais elegante seria não calcular a diferença de tempo usando as funções `time()` e `elaptime()`, mas apenas a função `seconds()`. Esta função retorna o número de segundos (com precisão de milésimos) decorridos desde a meia noite do dia atual até o presente momento. Você elimina totalmente qualquer necessidade de conversão de tempo. Veja como ficaria o código baseado no seu exemplo, assumindo que `nTimeOut` está expresso em segundos:

```
nTimeSec := seconds()
While seconds() - nTimeSec < nTimeOut 
    cResponse := VerifyOnServ(nTimeOut)
    If cResponse != nil
       EXIT
    EndIf
EndDo
```